# JQuery .click, .on not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I've had this problem for awhile now and I'm not sure what's up with it. 
I've tried everything including `.click()`, `.on()`, `.delegate` and I used `.find()` to try to look for the element in question but for some reason this click won't work...

```js
$('.fa').on("click",function({
    alert("hi");
});
```

```css
.main .header {
  background: #999;
  min-height: 80px;
}
.main .header ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main .header .nav-settings {
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.main .header .nav-settings li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.main .header .nav-settings li:hover {
  background: #2dbde4;
}
.main .header .nav-settings li a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav-settings">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="user">Josh</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a minor syntax error

try

```
$('.fa').on('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/t2jjff34/)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing parenthesis:

```
$('.fa').on("click",function(e){
//----------------------------^
    alert("hi");
});
```